# Can the kicker alter the shape of the football before a kickoff, say by banging the tips on the ground?

Tags: rules, nfl

During the Chiefs-Broncos game in December 2017, I notice that the Chiefs' kicker banged the tips of the football on the ground before placing it in the kick stand, thus altering the shape of the football.

That doesn't seem right to me; was it legal?

Comment: Are you sure the shape was altered?

Comment: Will a football that has between 12.5 and 13.5 psi of air in it and is designed to stand up to the abuse of a game including being kicked really deform so easily?

Answer (score 0):

Kickers as well as football players in general do not like to play with new balls. This is because they are harder, slicker and don’t perform as well in general. Because of this they do any they can to break in balls before they use them which can include squeezing or pressing them into the ground.

There is lots of information on this available with a search.

https://www.reddit.com/r/nfl/comments/11nuzw/why_do_kickers_press_in_the_ends_of_the_football/